# Debugging application crashes both Eclipse and Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have a really peculiar situation. I've created some code that seems to crash IDE's. Both Eclipse and Android Studio crash at a certain point.

With Eclipse I get a `org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException: Timeout occurred while waiting for packet xxx` exception. And the debugger disconnects.

Android Studio just crashes totally and doesn't respond anymore.

Let me give a detailed description of what I am trying to do, it surprises me since it isn't even a very complicated situation.

**The problem**

I have a fragment, which needs to reload its data when a certain parameter is changed. This paramater (`isRecent`) is located in the Activity. The target fragments that need to be reloaded are in a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. These fragments (3 in total) all extend from the abstract class `MovieFragment`, this fragment does all the data handling and calls an abstract method `doneLoadingData()` to inform the instances that the data is loaded.

When a navigation drawer item is selected, I loop trough a map inside the FragmentPagerAdapter to get a specific fragment, and call the method that gets the again BUT I also change the Activity's parameter: `isRecent` to true.

Now this all works fine. But when I try to return to this previous state, so get new data but the isRecent is set back to 'false', the `getData()` is called twice for some reason and the second time it returns null, causing an error message to display in my app. Now of course I tried to debug the situation in the `AsyncTask` and see what happens the second time the `AsyncTask` gets called. But here both IDE's fail to debug the project. The app runs when I don't debug, but when I debug they quit.

**The code**

My MovieFragment gets it's data the following way:

```
public void getData(String language, boolean isNewDataset) {
    // isNewDataset is true if getData() is called for a total new dataset
    // this means for initial init and for switching between fragments
    // recent and in theaters
    if (isNewDataset) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noMoviesLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        movieListView.setAdapter(null);
        resetLocalVariables();
        resetChildren();
    }

    ShortFilmFetcher filmFetcher = new ShortFilmFetcher(
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).isRecentSelected());
    filmFetcher.execute(new String[] { language });
}
```

The `resetLocalVariables()` methods are just for resetting all the local variables, same goes for `resetChildren()` but that is an abstract method that gets called to reset some private properties in the children fragments.

The `AsyncTask`, ShortFilmFetcher looks like this:

```
class ShortFilmFetcher extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FlikrFilmObj> {

    String language;
    boolean isRecentEnabled;

    public ShortFilmFetcher(boolean isRecent) {
        this.isRecentEnabled = isRecent;
    }

    @Override
    protected FlikrFilmObj doInBackground(String... params) {
        language = params[0];
        try {
            Log.d("recent", "is recent enabled: " + isRecentEnabled);
            if (language.equals("tamil")) {
                return FlikrUtil.getFilms(language, tamilVideoStart,
                        isRecentEnabled);
            } else if (language.equals("hindi")) {
                return FlikrUtil.getFilms(language, hindiVideoStart,
                        isRecentEnabled);
            } else { // english
                return FlikrUtil.getFilms(language, englishVideoStart,
                        isRecentEnabled);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(FlikrFilmObj result) {
        if (result != null && result.getShortFilms() != null
                && result.getShortFilms().size() > 0) {
            if (language.equals("tamil")) {
                dataLoadingDone("tamil", result, !(tamilVideoStart == 1));
                tamilVideoStart += result.getVideoCount();
                tamilEndReached = result.isEndReached();
            } else if (language.equals("hindi")) {
                dataLoadingDone("hindi", result, !(hindiVideoStart == 1));
                hindiVideoStart += result.getVideoCount();
                hindiEndReached = result.isEndReached();
            } else { // english
                dataLoadingDone("english", result,
                        !(englishVideoStart == 1));
                englishVideoStart += result.getVideoCount();
                englishEndReached = result.isEndReached();
            }
        } else {
            if (result != null) {
                noMoviesLabel.setText("No movies available");
            } else {
                noMoviesLabel.setText("Error while retrieving movies");
            }
            noMoviesLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

}
```

Now this is nothing too special, the request I'm doing works and doesn't deliver any problems in other situations.

In my MainActivity when I change the isRecent value and reload the data:

```
private void navigateToRecentAndTheaters(boolean isRecent) {
    // remove previous fragments
    FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
    if (fManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fManager.popBackStack();
    }
    pagerTabStrip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // modify the theater fragments
    isRecentSelected = isRecent;
    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        MovieFragment hFragment = (MovieFragment) mAdapter.getItemAt(i);
        if (i == 0) {
            hFragment.getData("hindi", true);
        } else if (i == 1) {
            hFragment.getData("tamil", true);
        } else {
            hFragment.getData("english", true);
        }
    }
}
```

I sincerely hope someone can guide me in the right direction here. Why the hell is the code working (kind of) and the debugger crashing?

Comment: You're certainly doing some intensive tasks at AsyncTask. As a suggestion, try to remove code (comment them out), and run in the debugger again, and see if the problem anomaly still happens. Another words, isolate the issue.  And I think post the full, or fuller, logcat error messages in your post will be good. Perhaps we can see the root cause of the problem.

Comment: If the debugger crashes, the log will show exceptions. These will tell you what goes wrong.

Comment: @Christine Eclipse did show an error message (jdi.TimeOutException), Anroid Studio simply totally freezed.